# Positioning element relative to absolute positioned element within absolute parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sass

I want to position tutorial messages to the location of HTML elements. E.g., "Click Here" pointing to a particular element. I'm using SCSS for CSS and jQuery.

The element `.target-element` (the yellow ">" arrow) is positioned absolute within an absolutely positioned parent `.target-element-container` (the white speech bubble). I want to position `.tutorial-pointer` to point at `.target-element` (the yellow ">" arrow):

```
.game-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    .wrist-watch { // the wrist watch image container
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 20px;
        left: 20px;
        .target-element-container { // the speech bubble
            width: 200px;
            min-height: 88px;
            background: #fff;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
            padding: 20px;
            position: absolute;
            right: -102px;
            top: -166px;

            .target-element { // the yellow ">" arrow
                position: absolute;
                right: 4px;
                bottom: 4px;
                width: 25px;
                height: 25px;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The tutorial pointer (the element I'll be moving around to point at various target elements) has the class:

```
.tutorial-pointer { // the blue "Click" arrow
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

I want to move the tutorial arrow (`.tutorial-pointer`) to the location of `.target-element`, so I'm using `.offset()`.

**Set Arrow positioning:**

```
let elPosition = $('.target-element').offset();

let top = elPosition.top;
let left = elPosition.left;

$('.tutorial-pointer').css({
    top: `${top}px`,
    left: `${left}px`,
});
```

**The Problem:** The positioning doesn't seem to be working on different screen sizes. On a smaller width screen, the arrow is positioned perfectly:

[image]

On a larger width screen, it's offset too far to the right:

[image]

If I'm getting the offset of `.target-element` at the time of placing the `.tutorial-pointer`, why should screen width matter?

Comment: what is the first `relative` parent of the absolute elements?

Comment: @quirimmo it's the game wrapper. See above for edited styles

Comment: you have a bit of mess with these negative values for `right` and `top`. If you see your screenshots, even the watch container itself has different positions (see the margin from left and bottom). IMO, you can start from scratch with a container, be sure that at least the container is displayed in the same way, avoiding the usage of negative right and top. Instead try to use width and height in pixels, and positions/margins then with percentage if the relative parent has standard size

Comment: @quirimmo Yeah it was tough to manage all the floating GUI elements necessary for the game so I got myself into a bit of a mess.

Comment: @quirimmo RE: `even the watch container itself has different positions (see the margin from left and bottom)` that was just a bad screenshot. The positions are the same for the watch. Re-uploaded new image

Comment: Also, I don't see how negative position `left/top` values affect the original question. I set top/left to `0` to test and the offset problem in the original question persists.

Comment: Can you post the HTML?